# Numeric pad problem

Tags: numpad

I have an HP Envy laptop with a numeric pad. I recently installed Ubuntu v. 18.04 alongside Windows 10. I can use the numeric pad to sign in to Ubuntu but as soon as the GUI appears, the numeric pad quits working.  The answers in Ubuntu One seemingly do not apply to v. 18.04. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Do you have NumLock on?

Comment: In addition to wjanrea's question, what happens if you hold down the 2, 4, 6, or 8 button? Does your mouse pointer move on the screen? If so, you need to disable Mouse Keys in Settings > Universal Access.

Answer (score 0):

If your cursor moves around the screen when you press the <kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd>,or <kbd>8</kbd>, keys, you need to disable Mouse Keys in Settings > Universal Access.